# Can't find module when dynamically importing in Angular Universal

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, importerror, angular-universal

Angular Universal can't find the module of dynamically imported files that contains a custom decorator

I've made a decorator. I'd like when it runs the code in the server.ts file, it'll import every file that uses my decorator. To do this I've made this:

```
function scanDirectory(directoryPath: string) {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(directoryPath)

    let filesUsingDecorators = Array<string>()

    for (const file of files) {
        const filePath = resolve(directoryPath, file)
        const stat = fs.statSync(filePath)

        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            filesUsingDecorators = [...filesUsingDecorators, ...scanDirectory(filePath)]
        }
        else if (stat.isFile()) {
            const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8')
            if (/@AutoImport/.test(fileContent)) {
                filesUsingDecorators.push(filePath)
            }
        }
    }

    return filesUsingDecorators
}

export function importFiles(directory: string) {
    const filesUsingDecorators = scanDirectory(directory)
    if (filesUsingDecorators.length == 0) return
    for (const filePath of filesUsingDecorators) {
        const relativePath = filePath!.replace(/\\/g, "/").slice(0, -3)
        import(relativePath)
    }
}
```

And then I'm calling importFiles inside server.ts like this:
`importFiles ("src/server")`

This works perfectly in a normal express project. But here in Angular Universal, it finds the file, is not able to find a modules and comes up with this error:
"Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot find module 'C:/projects/angular/universal-project/src/server/mail-logger' ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot find module 'C:/projects/angular/universal-project/src/server/mail-logger'"

I'm guessing it's not working correctly since AU transpiles everything in the dist folder and then is not able to import dynamically on runtime. How can I make it work?